# Does Dalvik listen to log / debug message?

Tags: javascript, android, dalvik

Javascript code in html seems to run on libwebcore.so when looking into trace profile if the js code computes only array elements without any graphics.
However, when I just added console.log in js code, the profile showed increase of instruction counts on libdvm.so. I guess this result tells that Dalvik seems to listen to or get some log message from kernel, and do something.
My guess is correct? 
"adb logcat" in terminal enables me to check messages from "console.log" in js code.
Dalvik interacts with this message??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dalvik does not read the logcat output.  The only interaction between the VM and the logs is if you enable stdio conversion (`setprop log.redirect-stdio true`) and then write to stdout or stderr, but I doubt this is what is happening here.

You would see an increase of activity in Java code if the Javascript logging implementation called back into Java for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! My first guess was wrong in the question, but as you mentioned, javascript logging may invoke Java for some reason, which in turn affects instruction counts on Dalvik. But, I don't know how to prove or confirm it exactly. Anyway, thanks again.